# How to achieve a specific type of API in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to the Django rest framework and I am wanting to acheive this kind of API:

```
 {
    question_no: "1",
    question: "How many sides are equal in a scalene triangle?",
    options: [
        { que_options: "3", selected: false, isCorrect: true },
        { que_options: "2", selected: false, isCorrect: true },
        { que_options: "0", selected: false, isCorrect: true },
    ],
},
```

How can I achieve the above type of API?

I have tried to make make it work with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class AnswerOptions(models.Model):
    option= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    isCorrect = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Quiz(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    options = models.ManyToManyField(AnswerOptions)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a Model Structure?

Comment: Youre missing a model here. And also, can you post the serialiser that you have written so we can help you change it so that it works. Please also update your answer to include and errors or specific problems youre encountering.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this kind of api you need to create a proper serializers. It should look something like this:

```
class AnswerOptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AnswerOption
        fields = ('__all__')

class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answeroption_set = AnswerOptionSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ('__all__')
```

You also need to remember to create the right view. If your assumption is to display a list of results then I would use ListAPIView.

```
class MyListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
    queryset = Quiz.objects.all()
```